# Horizontal scrolling and vertical scrolling in JqueryMobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I want to implement horizontal scrolling with vertical sliding .Something like picture given below.[image]

For doing the same I search and found this one http://developingwithstyle.blogspot.co.uk/2010/11/jquery-mobile-swipe-up-down-left-right.html
But the code written in this blog does not make sense to me.

I also downloaded the demo provided at http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/ and try to modified according to my need. But could not able to do the same.
If any one have Idea or link or demo project then please help me.
Regards!

Comment: are you looking for a horizontal and vertical combined together?

Comment: @Omar : Yes exactly the same you are thinking.

Comment: @Will etc. This question is not off-topic. The user has demonstrated some investigation into the problem. albeit with limited understanding of the technology.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Update

> I have made some major modification, which give more control over touch events. You can now set minimum/maximum values of touch *duration*, *distance*, and *threshold* for both X and Y axis.
>
> Moreover, images now are **preloaded** for smoother transition between images.

---

I have made this rather *complicated* code based on touch events `touchstart` and `touchend`, horizontally and vertically. The code catches touch events and then interpret them into swipe *up*, *right*, *down* and *left*.

Images are exchanged with `.animate()` according to swipe's direction. Swipe *up* and *left*, load next images in *array*; *down* and *right* load previous ones.

<strike>It is somehow lengthy, and have too much room of enhancement. For instance, you can calculate time elapsed between both events *touchstart* and *touchend* to ensure that the touch was sufficient enough to trigger custom swipes.</strike>

I'll go through code's main parts for more explanation.

#### HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">
    <!-- images go here -->
   </div>
</div>
```

---

#### CSS

1. Wrapper - *height* and *width* should be adjusted to your need:

   ```
   .wrapper {
     overflow: hidden;
     position: relative;
     height: 200px;
     width: 400px;
     margin: 0 auto;
   }
   ```
2. Inner wrapper - To append images to:

   ```
   .inner {
     height: 200px;
     width: auto;
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
     white-space: nowrap;
   }
   ```
3. Transition wrappers - Used for images transition *in* and *out*:

   ```
   .holder, .in, .hidden {
     position: absolute;
   }
   ```
4. Hide preloaded images:

   ```
   .hidden {
     display: none;
   }
   ```

---

#### JS

1. Variables and defaults:

   ```
   var total = images.length - 1, /* images total number */
       current = 0,               /* image's index */
       startX = '',               /* touchstart X coordinate */ 
       startY = '',               /* touchstart Y coordinate */
       endX = '',                 /* touchend X coordinate */
       endY = '';                 /* touchend Y coordinate */
       swipeDuration = 1000,      /* max touch duration */
       swipeDistanceX = 50,       /* X-axis min touch distance */
       swipeDistanceY = 50,       /* Y-axis min touch distance */
       thresholdX = 30,           /* X-axis max touch displacement */
       thresholdY = 30;           /* Y-axis max touch displacement */
   ```
2. Preload images:

   Wrap each one in `holder` and then append them to `inner` div, on `pageinit` event or any other [jQM page events](http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/).

   ```
   $(document).on("pageinit", "#gallery", function () {
       $.each(images, function (i, src) {
           $("<div class='holder hidden'><img src=" + src + " /></div>").appendTo(".inner");
       });
       $(".inner .holder:first-child").toggleClass("visible hidden");
   });
   ```
3. Touch events interpretation - bind Touch events to `inner` div:

   Touch *duration* and *distance* are added to comparison.

   ```
   $(document).on("touchstart", ".inner", function (e, ui) {
       startX = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
       startY = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
       start = new Date().getTime(); /* touch start */
   }).on("touchmove", ".inner", function (e, ui) {

       /* prevent page from scrolling */
       e.preventDefault();

   }).on("touchend", ".inner", function (e, ui) {
       endX = e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageX;
       endY = e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageY;
       end = new Date().getTime(); /* touch end */
       if ((end - start) < swipeDuration) {
         if (startX > endX && Math.abs(startY - endY) <= thresholdY && Math.abs(startX - endX) >= swipeDistanceX) {
           showImg(current, "left");
         } else if (startX < endX && Math.abs(startY - endY) <= thresholdY && Math.abs(startX - endX) >= swipeDistanceX) {
            showImg(current, "right");
         } else if (startY > endY && Math.abs(startX - endX) <= thresholdX && Math.abs(startY - endY) >= swipeDistanceY) {
           showImg(current, "up");
         } else if (startY < endY && Math.abs(startX - endX) <= thresholdX && Math.abs(startY - endY) >= swipeDistanceY) {
           showImg(current, "down");
         }
       }
   });
   ```
4. Transition `showImg(image index, swipe type)` function:

   Added *opacity* to animation.

   ```
   function showImg(index, type) {
       if (type == "left") {
           current = index;
           if (current >= 0 && current < total) {
               current++;
               var distance = $(".visible").width();
               $(".inner .holder").eq(current).css({
                   left: distance
               }).toggleClass("in hidden");

               $(".visible").animate({
                   left: "-" + distance + "px",
                   opacity: 0
               }, 600, function () {
                   $(this).toggleClass("visible hidden").css({
                       top: "auto",
                       left: "auto"
                   });
               });

               $(".in").animate({
                   left: 0,
                   opacity: 1
               }, 500, function () {
                   $(this).toggleClass("in visible");
               });
           }
       }

       if (type == "up") {
           current = index;
           if (current >= 0 && current < total) {
               current++;
               var distance = $(".visible").height();
               $(".inner .holder").eq(current).css({
                   top: distance + "px"
               }).toggleClass("in hidden");

               $(".visible").animate({
                   top: "-" + distance + "px",
                   opacity: 0
               }, 600, function () {
                   $(this).toggleClass("visible hidden").css({
                       top: "auto",
                       left: "auto"
                   });
               });

               $(".in").animate({
                   top: 0,
                   opacity: 1
               }, 500, function () {
                   $(this).toggleClass("in visible");
               });
           }
       }

       if (type == "right") {
           current = index;
           if (current > 0 && current <= total) {
               current--;
               var distance = $(".visible").width();
               $(".inner .holder").eq(current).css({
                   left: "-" + distance + "px"
               }).toggleClass("in hidden");

               $(".visible").animate({
                   left: distance + "px",
                   opacity: 0
               }, 600, function () {
                   $(this).toggleClass("visible hidden").css({
                       top: "auto",
                       left: "auto"
                   });
               });

               $(".in").animate({
                   left: 0,
                   opacity: 1
               }, 500, function () {
                   $(this).toggleClass("in visible");
               });
           }
       }

       if (type == "down") {
           current = index;
           if (current > 0 && current <= total) {
               current--;
               var distance = $(".holder").height();
               $(".inner .holder").eq(current).css({
                   top: "-" + distance + "px"
               }).toggleClass("in hidden");

               $(".visible").animate({
                   top: distance + "px",
                   opacity: 0
               }, 600, function () {
                   $(this).toggleClass("visible hidden").css({
                       top: "auto",
                       left: "auto"
                   });
               });

               $(".in").animate({
                   top: 0,
                   opacity: 1
               }, 500, function () {
                   $(this).toggleClass("in visible");
               });
           }
       }
   }
   ```

---

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/QXLY2/)** <sup>(1)</sup>

<sup>(1) Tested on iPad 2 and iPhone 5 - v7.0.4</sup>

Comment: very nicely done. I combined it with jquery.touchSwipe.min.js for better swipe detection, works great.

Comment: @grumpy I'm glad it worked well for you. If you're an expert in JS, you can do some modifications that makes it even better :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm currently at work so didnt had much time to work somethnig out. but created a little thing of 2 projects combined.

added the horizental scrolling to page 3.

http://jsfiddle.net/BL33k/

used some dutch in je javascript so:

```
var slideAantal = slides.length; //means slidetotal
var slideBreedte = screen.width; //means slidewidth
var beeldHoogte  = screen.height; //means slideheight
var slideHuidig  = 0; //means currentslide
```

Code is very dirty and there might be a lot of unessecery things but dont have time to go trough that now. Hope it helps you tho.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with simple CSS and some DOM manipulation http://jsfiddle.net/zTGS9/1/

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
        div {
            width: 500px;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }
        ul {
            list-style: none;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0;
        }
        li {
            clear: both;
            white-space: nowrap;
            position: relative;
            height: 200px;
            width: 100%;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            padding: 0;
        }
        img {
            -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
            -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
            -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
            transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
            position: absolute;
            display: block;
            top: 0;
        }
        img:nth-of-type(1) {
            left: -700px;
        }
        img:nth-of-type(2) {
            left: -300px;
        }
        img:nth-of-type(3) {
            left: 100px;
        }
        img:nth-of-type(4) {
            left: 500px;
        }
        img:nth-of-type(5) {
            left: 900px;
        }
        img:nth-of-type(6) {
            left: 1300px;
        }

    </style>
    <body>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/image%201/"/>
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/image%202/"/>
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/business/image%203/"/>
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food/image%204/"/>
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract/image%205/"/>
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/fashion/image%206/"/>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/image%202/"/>
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/image%203/"/>
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/business/image%204/"/>
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food/image%205/"/>
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract/image%206/"/>
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/fashion/image%207/"/>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/image%204/"/>
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/image%205/"/>
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/business/image%206/"/>
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food/image%207/"/>
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract/image%208/"/>
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/fashion/image%209/"/>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/image%209/"/>
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/image%208/"/>
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/business/image%207/"/>
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food/image%206/"/>
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract/image%205/"/>
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/fashion/image%204/"/>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
       var _lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < _lis.length; ++i) {
    _lis[i].addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
        if (e.clientX < (this.offsetWidth >> 1)) {
            this.appendChild(this.removeChild(this.firstElementChild));
        } else {
            this.insertBefore(this.lastElementChild, this.firstElementChild);
           }
    });
}
    </script>
</html>
```

No time to implement touch events, but I hope you get the idea :)

Comment: this will retain device scrolling in y

Answer (score -2):

You need to apply inline css for body tag .

```
body{
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

for y scroll, see this http://sigmamobility.com/examples/appexamples.jsp.
note that applying above wont give intended results unless your controls are really overflow window width / height.

You can test your code through Sigma Mobility which enables creating mobile apps and easily inject inline css /js code along with real-time preview.