# what is the method to have swipe functionality with dynamic data in jquery mobile

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-mobile

what is the method to have swipe functionality with dynamic data in jquery mobile, i have used wow slider but the data is sliding normally that too i used static data. but what i need is swipe functionality with dynamic data can someone help me please thanks.

the code i am using now is as follows

```
<div id="content-area">


<br/>                   
                       <div id="wowslider-container1">
                            <div class="ws_images"><ul>
                                <li><img src="data1/images/home.png" alt="" title="" id="wows1_0"/>LENSPAL offers help through tips,videos, and reminders</li>
<li><img src="data1/images/reminder.png" alt="" title="" id="wows1_1"/>Reminders let you create alerts like when to remove your lenses or buy new ones.</li>
<li><img src="data1/images/track.png" alt="" title="" id="wows1_2"/> Track your progress so you can review it with your optometrist</li>
<li><img src="data1/images/video.png" alt="" title="" id="wows1_3"/>Useful content and videos to guide you through the insertion and removal of contact lenses</li>
                            </ul></div>
                            <div class="ws_bullets"><div>
                            <a href="#" title="home">1</a>
                            <a href="#" title="reminder">2</a>
                            <a href="#" title="track">3</a>
                            <a href="#" title="video">4</a>
                            </div></div>

    <div class="ws_shadow">

                    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/wowslider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear and lack details.

Comment: i want functionality for swipe the data dynamically from database in jquery mobile

Comment: Create your own widget instead of using plugins. Check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565126/horizontal-scrolling-and-vertical-scrolling-in-jquerymobile/20713996#20713996

Comment: any other solutions please