# How to contain multi-directional "touchmove" event

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch-event

I have created a *reactive* horizontal & vertical image gallery based on converting *touch events* into swipe *up*, *left*, *down* and *right*. <sup>(1)</sup>

Now, I am converting it into a *responsive* one, where next or previous element is dragged along with the active element on `touchmove`.

All is working as expected with no issues, except for that events are interfering when `touchmove` direction is deviated. For example, when moving to *left* and the movement drifts *up* or *down*, the later two events trigger causing in misplacing the elements.

I have tried `stopImmediatePropagation()` and comparisons `(dragDirection != "up" || dragDirection != "right" || dragDirection != "down")`, but still couldn't get rid of it.

Here is the code of *left* drag on `touchmove` event.

```
/* Left */
if (startX > moveX && XmoveTo > 10 && Math.abs(startY - moveY) < 10 && (dragDirection != "up" || dragDirection != "right" || dragDirection != "down")) {
    dragDirection = "left";
    e.stopImmediatePropagation(); /* has no effect */
    $(".visible").css({
        left: "-" + XmoveTo + "px"
    }).next().css({
        left: $(".visible").width() + "px"
    }).removeClass("hidden").css({
        left: $(".visible").width() - XmoveTo + "px",
        top: 0
    });
}
```

Please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/dqcYK/) for complete code and testing <sup>(2)</sup>. Drag image to any direction *(left & up = next / right & down = prev)* and then move diagonally. You will notice that images are misplaced.

<sup>(1)</sup> [Image gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20713996/1771795)

<sup>(2)</sup> [Emulating Touch Events - Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation#emulate-touch-events)