# How to make a gallery touch enabled?

Tags: jquery, html, css, touch

I am making a full screen gallery and now I want it to be touch enabled to be used with Ipad or mobile.
I am totally confused how to do that. I searched on the Internet but I am not able to understand fully. Maybe I need to use jQuery mobile? can someone please help.
thanks.

Comment: normaly this should work without the mobile jQuery version on iPad or iPhone, but it is better when you use also this code in your `<head>` tag.
`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: use `touch` events http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565126/horizontal-scrolling-and-vertical-scrolling-in-jquerymobile/20713996#20713996