# Photoswipe swipe controls on touch screens without jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, photoswipe

I have a page for an image gallery where I am using http://www.photoswipe.com/ to go between images in the gallery.  Everything works perfectly, except on mobile devices it does not recognize swipe gestures without the jquery mobile library.  I don't like using jquery mobile because it does too many of its own things with styling, adding stuff I don't want, etc.

The example I'm basing it off is here.  Basically trying to use this exact same page except without using jquery mobile:  http://www.gregoryjewellers.com.au/libraries/jquery/photoswipe/examples/04-jquery-mobile.html#Gallery1.  Except my photoswipe call is just:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myPhotoSwipe = $("#Gallery a").photoSwipe({ enableMouseWheel: true , enableKeyboard: true , preventDefaultTouchEvents: true });
});
```

Is there any way to implement Photoswipe with touch screen gestures without jquery mobile?  If so, is there an example out there?

Comment: If just want to create left/right swipe, you really don't need any extra plugin. You can create them yourself. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565126/horizontal-scrolling-and-vertical-scrolling-in-jquerymobile/20713996#20713996 check JS part #3 how to use `touch` events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is PhotoSwipe is built on top of jQuery Mobile library. jQuery Mobile is activating on links and divs having data-role="page" attribute. mostly you might be messing with links(anchor tags). If so use rel="external" in links.

Comment: It's a mixture of links and that it adds a div in there, adds stuff to the body tag, etc, which seems to really screw up my layout.  I don't want jquery mobile to touch any of my HTML unless I want it to, I just and I don't see any way to prevent that from happening.