# How to implement jQuery mobile page (vertical) swipe?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, swipe-gesture

I'm using `jQuery mobile 1.4.2` and can't get the `pages to swipe vertically`. Can someone who has successfully implemented this feature, show me how it's done, along with sample code?

Also what version of jQuery should I use with latest jQuery mobile, since latest ones tend to break the functionality.

Comment: fix the height and give overflow : auto

Comment: you will need to use `touch` events to create a custom swipeup/swipedown events. similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20713996/1771795